# VB6: How to sort an array of numbers but match up the corresponding string(text) value after

Tags: vba, vb6

I'm having a bit of trouble with a section of my code. I have to use VB6 for assignment don't ask why, I know it's old, wouldn't have been my first choice. I need to put into order a text file leaderboard, I have 2 files one with the score of the player and another with the name of the player (each line of each text file correspond with name and score value). I am fine with sorting the scores and displaying them in a list box but just cannot think how to match the string/text value with the appropriate score after? If anybody could help it would be greatly appreciated.

A small section of the code I have used for sorting the integer score values but now from here don't know how to add the string/text player name to that corresponding sorted score:

```
num = UBound(strPreviousScores)

For i = 0 To num
    SortedScores(i) = Val(strUnsortedScores(i))
Next i


For i = 0 To num
    For j = i + 1 To num
        If Sortedscores(i) < SortedScores(j) Then
            temp = SortedScores(i)
            SortedScores(i) = SortedScores(j)
            SortedScores(j) = temp
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'''''
intCounter = 0
For k = 0 To 4
    lstScores.AddItem SortedScores(intCounter)
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
Next
'''''
```

Thank You

Jack

Comment: Re-order the elements in other array at the same time you sort the scores array

Comment: If I understand what you're doing correctly, it sounds like you need a user `Type` with `Player` and `Score` members.

Answer (score 1):

One option, suggested by @Comintern, would be an array of a UDT with two members.

An option that keeps your existing arrays would be to add an index array. You create an integer array having the same number of elements as your current arrays, and "self-fill" it: each entry has as its value, the value of its index: Idx(1) = 1, Idx(2) = 2 etc

Then as you sort on the scores, you access the array via the index array, [ as in, Scores(Idx(x)) ] and swap the index values, not the Scores values. When you're done, Idx(1) has the value of the index of the lowest Scores value. That same index can be used to access the Players array.

This is way easier to do than to explain. Google "indexed sort" for examples.

Part of possible code, from your example:

```
 If Scores(Idx(i)) < Scores(Idx(j)) Then
    temp = Idx(i)
    Idx(i) = Idx(j)
    Idx(j) = temp
 End If
```